# Integration Order Change

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have this integration

$$\int_{y=0}^{1} \int_{z=0}^{x^2+y^2}$$

and I want to use the order change method to get $dy dz$ instead. However, when I try that I obtain the following,

$$\int_{z=0}^{1+x^2} \int_{y=z-x^2}^{1}$$

but alas they don't give the same result. When I plot the boundaries, I can see the function doesn't *really* go from $(z-x^2) \to 1$ but I can't really figure out how and why.

Comment: I don't understand, you should have three variables, isn't it a triple integral?

Comment: Yeah, it's $$\int_{x=0}^{1} \int_{y=0}^{1} \int_{z=0}^{x^2+y^2} $$, but since I'm only interested in the order change of the inner part, I didn't want to include it. Does it change anything for the inner integral?

Comment: Ah ok, you need to make a plot of the domain, to invert z and y you need to divide the integral in two parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

$$\int_{0}^{1} dx \int_{0}^{1}dy \int_{0}^{x^2+y^2}dz=\int_{0}^{1} dx \int_{0}^{x^2}dz \int_{0}^{1}dy+\int_{0}^{1} dx \int_{x^2}^{1+x^2}dz \int_{\sqrt{z-x^2}}^{1}dy$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! But, shouldn't 

$$ \int_0^1 dx \int_{0}^{x^2+1} dz \int_{\sqrt{z-x^2}}^{1} dy $$ be 

$$\int_0^1 dx \int_{x^2}^{x^2+1} dz \int_{\sqrt{z-x^2}}^{1} $$

Comment: @ofey I've updated! there was a typo but it's different form your!  check I'm adding also a sketch

Comment: Thanks again! By the way the image gives 404.

Comment: @ofey 404? I see it!

Comment: Ah sorry, all imgur links were redirected to 0imgur, so it was causing that. So, from your image, shouldn't the the value on the z axis above $1$ be $x^2 + 1$, because the function is $z = x^2 + y^2 $ for $y=1$ or am I mistaken?

Comment: @ofey oh yes of course you are absolutely right, Sorry, I update!

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!